# How to print the total available space percentage on a specific file system in both linux and solaris?

Tags: linux, solaris, environment-variables, disk-usage

I've searched for an answer to this question and I found that this command:

```
df /dev/sda1 | awk {print '{(100 -$5 )}' | tail -1 | sed '/s/$/%/g'
```

does the job pretty well on my linux system but I want to make sure that this works on a solaris PC as well. `/dev/sda1` is the filesystem that consumes the most disk space on my HDD. If I won't put any parameters on `df` it will print out that I have 99% of available space.

Are there any enviromental variables that can replace the filesystem `/dev/sda1` (I haven't found one) so that the previous command works on solaris as well or is there any specific parameter for the `df` command?

Comment: What was your criteria for choosing `/dev/sda1` to measure?

Comment: You can also use `df` against a directory or file to get filesystem data for the filesystem the directory or file is part of:  `df /` will show the data for the root filesystem on both Linux and Solaris.

Answer (score 4):

```
df -P / | awk '/%/ {print 100 -$5 "%"}'
```

`-P` makes `df` use the POSIX standard in Linux, and a format which is equivalent on POSIX compliant systems [which is explained here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html).

`awk` is [a POSIX standard tool](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) as well.

Since all tools are POSIX standard they should work on all POSIX systems, and I cut down on two PIDs by merging `tail` and `sed` into awk.

Comment: nitpick: _they should work on all POSIX systems_... provided they are invoked in a POSIX environment (POSIX doesn't require a POSIX environment to be the default (a system could conform to several standards) and in practice systems like GNU (where you need `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=something`) or Solaris (where you need to follow the instructions in `standards(5)`) don't). For instance GNU `df -P` still doesn't output values in 512-byte blocks unless you call it as `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df -P` (not an issue here), Solaris default df doesn't support `-P`, you need to invoke `/usr/xpg4/bin/df` there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas learning experience for everyone. I appreciate the correction however. It's too bad you still have to know the environment you're using to know which version to use (w/r/t `/usr/xpg4/bin/df`)